# Magento- can´t login a determinate number of customer in the frontend

Tags: magento, authentication

later days ago some clients of my online store complain me that theys can´t login in yours account section.
Later many hour looking in Google I can find the generic problem.

In this link for example:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/answers/discussion/900/Customers-cant-login-some-hours-after-register/p1

In some pages say me solve the issue:

1. Go to backend
2. search the customer
3. click in save customer since customer page witouth any change of customer dates.

nice, this solve my problem, however this is an solution per a particular customer.

The error in error.log is:

```
 [error] [client x.x.x.x] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 201326592 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 84 bytes) in /var/www/domain/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 290, referer: http://www.domain.com/customer/account/login/
```

I think this is a problem of maintenance of Database, then when you click in save customer Magento run some SQL to restart autoincrements of tables, and work fine.

I my progress to gain the inception of the error, I try find diferences between sql before/aftre then.

1. create copy of the database with mysqldump
2. add to git
3. solve the problem, with the above method
4. create another copy of the database with mysqldump( I sure thata no new clients in this period between copies).
5. view the diferences with git

I can see very diferences with the AUTOINCREMENTS:

```
   /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `core_session` ENABLE KEYS */;
@@ -5592,3 +5592,3 @@ CREATE TABLE `cron_schedule` (
   KEY `scheduled_at` (`scheduled_at`,`status`)
-) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=192949 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=192955 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;<br /><br />   /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customer_address_entity` ENABLE KEYS */;
@@ -5796,3 +5796,3 @@ CREATE TABLE `customer_address_entity_varchar` (
   CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_VARCHAR_ENTITY_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
-) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44118 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44121 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;<br /><br /> /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `customer_entity` ENABLE KEYS */;
@@ -6001,3 +6001,3 @@ CREATE TABLE `customer_entity_int` (
   CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_INT_ENTITY_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
-) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12841 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12843 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;<br /><br />@@ -6069,3 +6069,3 @@ CREATE TABLE `customer_entity_varchar` (
   CONSTRAINT `FK_CUSTOMER_VARCHAR_ENTITY_TYPE` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `eav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
-) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44866 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=44870 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;<br /><br />
```

how I can solve this general problem with Magento?, How I can Manitenance the DB to customer login succesful in my store?.

My Magento version 1.5.1.0

Many thanks, I think this is a important problem. 
Is very interesting the solution for the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Memory_limit no less than 256Mb (preferably 512)

Comment: but I don´t understand why the problem solve when save since backend or clean the cookies.

Comment: The problem is that customer data array when they log in is filling the memory limit of your server thus causing your issues, by increasing your memory limit to the Magento recommendations, you can avoid this issue.  This was a server side issue and had nothing to do with Magento itself, just the data that is was attempting to load.

Comment: I increment Memory_limit, this solve in part the problem,however this occurs less times, but this occurs. Like I to understand why this error occurs?? Is a huge quantity of memory :(

Comment: you have to debug it with profiler to see where your site leaks memory on this.

Comment: whatever profiler you know how to use, xdebug would give you more insight on this than built in. Detecting memory leaks is not easy and there is a bit of learning curve